# How to plot pcolor image for diifferent calsses using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have known something about for `pcolor` image using `matplotlib` for a simple dataset. however, if I have two dataset including classes data  and attribute dataset related to classes dataset.

```
classes_dataset = np.array([["a","b","b"],["a","c","a"],["b","c","c"]])
attribute_dataset = np.array([[0.1,0.9,0.6],[0.2,0.4,0.2],[0.7,0.8,1.0]])
```

where 0.1,0.2,and 0.2 are attribute for class a, 0.9,0.6,and 0.7 are attribute for class b, and 0.4,0.8,and 1.0 are attribute for class c

Thus, I want a pcolor image containg both classes information and attribute information. For class a, b, c, the cmap would be different.

thanks sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Transform your class array to an index, then when you plot your data, specify an array to `C` to set the color, and if `v` is a vector with the index for each point, use:

```
C=attribute_dataset[v]
```

Comment: i have upload a example drawing using excel, can i achieve using this approach?

Comment: Please don't rollback edits that make your post readable. Add the image properly without destroying them!

Comment: i am sorry for that

Comment: You will have to be more precise to get a more precise answer then. `pcolor` works with what I gave you.